# is there any size limit for pdf in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created small poc using hyperledger fabric and composer.
In my project, I am uploading 2 files,
for the first time the file getting uploaded but when I am trying to upload the second file of same size it show error in the composer

> Unhandled error for request POST /api/UpdateContractDetails: Error: request entity too large
>       at readStream (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:196:17)
>       at getRawBody (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12)
>       at read (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:76:3)
>       at jsonParser (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:127:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at /home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/token.js:130:7
>       at /home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/common/models/access-token.js:108:15
>       at /home/ttandale/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/common/models/access-token.js:171:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So technically, this is a Node question. Using Javascript, eg. `fs.readFileSync(‘yourimageFile.jpg’).toString(‘base64’);`, you should be able to convert the image to a Base64 string in your code. You can define 'String' for your chosen (modeled Asset type etc) field to host in Hyperledger Composer. The theory is that, once it is a string,  it is sent to the chaincode just like any other string.

these links may help:

->  https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/convert-an-uploaded-image-to-a-base64-string-in-node-js/

-> https://belltane.wordpress.com/2017/03/27/storing-images-in-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/

Comment: HI Paul, Iam converting it into base64  using this code : reader.readAsDataURL(newFile);
    reader.onload = function () {
          base64file=reader.result;
      string = base64file.substring(28);
            $scope.locDoc =  string ; 
            var details = {};
            details.locDoc =$scope.locDoc;

Comment: I am using anguler js for this