# Composer rest server entity too large

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm storing images in fabric blockchain as base64 strings. Here, whenever I try to interact(update or add assets including base64 strings) with the blockchain through the composer rest server, it throws below error,

```
Error: request entity too large
```

How to increase the request size limit or what are other possible approaches to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to edit the maximum request size of the REST server by editing the `server.js` located in  `path_to_rest_server/server/`. I edited below code,

```js
// Support JSON encoded bodies.
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.json());

// Support URL encoded bodies.
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
}));
```

to,

```js
// Support JSON encoded bodies.
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.json({
  strict: false,
  limit: "10000kb"
}));

// Support URL encoded bodies.
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: "10000kb"
}));
```

`10000kb` is the size limit.