# How to store large file in Hyperledger Fabric using Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Hi I created an asset in Composer model file.

```
asset Car identifiedby assetId{
o String assetId
o String data
}
```

when I am trying to put large file above 30kb, it is throwing error as data too large. So, **what is the limit of data that can be stored in a variable?**

**Is this the wrong way of storing files in blockchain(Hyperledger Fabric using Composer)?**

there are questions available for storing file in hyperledger fabric/composer. However, there is no question for storing large file.

Comment: The limitation is not the variable. Generally speaking, it is the wrong way - ie this approach is not recommended - see more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464591/what-is-the-best-way-of-image-storage-on-hyperledger-composer?noredirect=1&lq=1. You should save the files outside the blockchain eg via a secured storage service ?  and keep the hashes of the location saved in the ledger. Someone also posted this https://github.com/Preetam007/hyperledger_composer_file_storage as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see these answers and guidelines (on what to store etc) on these Stack Overflow resources: [is there any size limit for pdf in hyperledger fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155690/is-there-any-size-limit-for-pdf-in-hyperledger-fabric) and also this -> [what is the best way of image storage on hyperledger composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464591/what-is-the-best-way-of-image-storage-on-hyperledger-composer/49489574#49489574) - in the comment section it has a link to a Github resource for alternatives such as IPFS

Comment: My question is not about the best way to store file. I have seen both questions of which you have provided links. However I want to know what is the file size that can be stored in data field of asset that I have used.

Comment: ECMAScript Programming Language Specification does not specify a maximum for String AFAIK. Your heading asked 'how to' and that's what I answered.

Comment: Paul when I am pushing even a 32kb file it says file size too large. Is there  way I can store it in asset parameter.