# Storing data directly into CouchDB while using composer BNA on the Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install large file into Hyperledger composer as a field of an asset however it throws error.

I am now planning to store data into Fabric couchDB while using Hyperledger composer for chaincode(BNA), so I will store document hash into the asset field and file itself into couchDB.

**My question : is it possible to store data into couchDB directly while using hyperledger composer?**

[link to composer storing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743406/how-to-store-large-file-in-hyperledger-fabric-using-hyperledger-composer)

Comment: No. The Fabric CouchDB is for storing the world state as described here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/couchdb_as_state_database.html . CouchDB runs as a separate database process alongside the peer. The other question has been answered (not a Composer error btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not possible to store Data into CouchDB directly**. CouchDB instance runs in docker and one instance is created for every Peer.

State of an asset at any given time is stored in CouchDB. We cannot have direct access to the Database.